# How to update database via scanning a QR code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qr-code

I can make the QR code in rails. Making QR code with URL and scan it, using scanner in Samsung phone browser, I can have the browser load up the specified URL.

So I want to make a website that track item quantity in the storage. User will scan the QR code on the item as they take it out. Updating the quantity in the db.

Every url I tried are GET request, and I need PATCH request.

As I only have 2 weeks experiences with rails, this is probably something stupid and there are better ways. Im all open for any solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QR codes can only have GET requests. No way to perform a PATCH request. Just connect the URL to a method, which updates your database record.

in `routes.rb`:

```
get '/your_path', to: 'controller_name#action_name'
```

Comment: Thanks it now works as intended, it amazes me how such a simple method eluded me.

Im a little concern about security, could anything be done aside from updating the quantity of the db? The QR should only be on the items, so outsider shouldnt have access.

Comment: Whoever has access to this qrcode (or the URL) can invoke the method. You should be concerned about security, yes. You can still protect the URL with basic auth or require user to authenticate.

Comment: I think scanning the QR leading to directly altering the db is quite insecure. I will have it take the user to the item's page, where they can log in and make manual change to the quantity. Even if my co-workers are lazy, they should do at least that much!

Comment: You are partially right. If you protect the action directly it doesn't matter that much if you bring them to the list or execute the action directly. The important thing is that the URL is accessible only when the user is logged in. If you are using devise a simple `before_action authenticate_user!` will do it and, once authenticated, the user is brought back to the original URL and the action is performed.

Comment: I want to make it as simple as possible, since my co-workers are quite too unorganised and somewhat unwilling to do more to amend that. But keeping it secure is important too.